# React render arrow function performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I was reading couple articles that recommended not to use arrow functions in JSX attributes like onClick, onMouseMove etc.

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#is-it-ok-to-use-arrow-functions-in-render-methods

But when it comes to performance impact w.r.t usage of arrow function in JSX. 
Is there a difference in the below methods used to render x & y & z. Which would be the recommended approach in general?

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/different-ways-to-create-react-components-sm517

```
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const z = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
class MyComponent2 extends React.Component {
  showY = () => {
    return y.map(val => {
      return <p>{val}</p>;
    });
  };
  render() {
    const zValues = z.map(val => {
      return <p>{val}</p>;
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>React Component Using a Class</p>
          {x.map(val => {
            return <p>{val}</p>;
          })}
        </div>
        <div>{this.showY()}</div>
        <div>{zValues}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you link the articles you read, please?

Comment: `showY` should be a normal method definition. There's no good reason to use a class field with a function expression

Comment: Specifically this one -> https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#is-it-ok-to-use-arrow-functions-in-render-methods

Comment: There's absolutely no difference between using the temporary variable `zValues` and the direct embedding of the expression in jsx.

Comment: Got it thanks @Bergi

Comment: That article talks about *passing functions to components*. That's not what you're doing here, you're *calling* arrow functions.

Comment: Correct but i wanted to clarify if using arrow functions in general within render would cause any unintended perf. impacts.

Comment: In your example you are not passing arrow functions as props, the performance hit you take when you pass arrow functions or create objects **as props** is that even though props didn't change the virtual dom compare will fail and React will re render DOM. For example; `onClick={new=>"reference every render"}` or `someProp={{newly:"created object every render"}}`. This is why you have hooks like useCallback and useMemo and you can use reselect to create selectors for useSelector and mapStateToProps for react-redux

Comment: @meteor Not any more than calling arrow functions in any other method.

Comment: Thanks I see what you'e saying @HMR

Answer (score 0):

It is not a difference if you will use arrow or simple functions. All rules about these 2 ways of declaring functions are actual and valid from javascript. So, it is your right to use one type of function or another.